# Substring Function and charindex

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am trying to extract only 1 piece on information for a column , in my column I have the following info

```
  Servers 

13.10.225 kyle:225 
13.10.225 kim:552
13.10.225 MIX:441
13.10.225 flip:235
13.10.225 hello:4568
13.10.225 tick:8231
13.10.225 back:2369
```

I want extract only the name without the ip , :, and the port .

Can someone please guide me to the right path please?

```
select len (substring(Servers, 1,(charindex(':', Servers+ ':') - 1 )))Name 
from List
```

Comment: In what you want to use C#, java, javascript, sql ?

Comment: Why are you doing `len` (length)? If that's not the only problem, take one example, then do `select charindex(':', Address + ':')`, then `select substring(Address, 1,(charindex(':', Address + ':') - 1 )` and see what that gives you. This should give you a decent idea of what's wrong.

Comment: String str = s.substring(s.lastIndexOf(":") + 1); use this.

Comment: That's not C#, nor do I think its Java

Comment: I don't see C#, Java, JavaScript or Android. I only see SQL. Please (in general) stick to only 1 language tag, especially if the question is only applicable to one of them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace @servers with your tablename

```
declare @servers table(name varchar(40))
insert @servers values('13.10.225 tick:8231')
insert @servers values('13.10.225 back:2369')

select left(name1, patindex('%_:%', name1)) as NewName
from @servers
cross apply (select stuff(name, 1, charindex(' ', name), '') name1) x
```

Result:

```
NewName
tick
back
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `PATINDEX` and `SUBSTRING`

```
DECLARE @STR NVARCHAR(100) = '13.10.225 kyle:225'
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(100) = SUBSTRING(@STR, CHARINDEX(' ', @STR), patindex('%:%', @str) - CHARINDEX(' ', @STR))
DECLARE @PORT VARCHAR(100) = SUBSTRING(@STR, PATINDEX('%:%', @STR) + 1, LEN(@NAME))

SELECT @NAME + ' ' + @PORT
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/c59d9/1

Answer (score 0):

i'll give you an example in c#:

if you have string `str` you can do:

```
int whiteSpaceIdx = str.IndexOf(' ');

string name = str.Substring(whiteSpaceIdx, str.IndexOf(':') - whiteSpaceIdx);
```

almost the same example can be achieved written in java, but you have to give some more information so we'll now exactly what you need

Comment: Tagged c# in error but basically I want my result to return to be only the name ie ; kyle

Comment: @user2763844 in what language. this code will return "kyle" in c#

Comment: @NoIdeaForName This answer is not really for the tags specified, so I do think it is better removed.  I don't want to mark you down though - as it was a OP error.  Code got me started down a totally wrong path, though, before I realised - case sensitive is a batch...

Answer (score 0):

You can use this :

```
DECLARE @STR NVARCHAR(100) = '13.10.225 kyle:225'
DECLARE @NAME VARCHAR(100) = SUBSTRING(@str, CHARINDEX(' ',@str)+1, (CHARINDEX(':',@str)-CHARINDEX(' ',@str))-1)

SELECT @name
```

This should help .